# 301 redirect from previous asp verion

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, http-redirect

I have found this. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221100823/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/shahed/archive/2007/10/23/116278.aspx)

Can some help me organise this into an aspx/aspx.cs file as I'm not overly familiar with all the code here.

Hi,

I have built a new website using asp.net. The previous version was built using asp. Here is the problem. My client wants 301 permanent redirects on pages with query strings.

How do I go about redirecting from a page that doesn't exist on my server any more eg.

From

[www.example.com/dolls/detail.asp?id=15](http://www.example.com/dolls/detail.asp?id=15)

to

[www.example.com/search_results.aspx?section=Dolls&title=Hat](http://www.example.com/search_results.aspx?section=Dolls&title=Hat)

I have read a few articles but they don't explain how to remedy this particular problem.

Many thanks,
C

Comment: Have you read the answers? Did any of them work for you?

Answer (score 0):

1) Apache: `Redirect 301 /detail.asp?id=15 http://www.mydomain.com/search_results.aspx?section=Dolls&title=Hat`

2) IIS: there is a redirection page.

3) **Edited**: full code:

```
using System.Web;
public class PermaRedirectHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public PermaRedirectHandler(){}

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.RedirectLocation = RedirectionClass.GetRedirectUrl(context);
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

In web config you would map all the paths ending .asp to the handler:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asp" name="redir" type="PermaRedirectHandler" modules="IsapiModule"/>
  ...
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

You will need a mapper for old=>new urls `RedirectionClass.GetRedirectUrl`. You could use a `Dictionary<string, string>` or whatever.

Comment: This is not what he ask for. And how they going to run asp pages from aspx compiler ?

Comment: Actually. Since he cannot suggest the paths, he could do it manually in server configuration.
Also added code that will handle the redirection.